# memoir marginfigure captions extending into footer

Tags: captions, memoir

I use `marginfigure` so that small figures can be right by the text referring to them. But I can't stop the captions extending into the footer.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% to load the image
\usepackage{graphicx}

% let's get that page number across to the figure
\pagestyle{ruled}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Use \textbackslash{}vfill to quickly get near the bottom of the page.

\vspace{6.5in}

Aaaand we're back. Now let's add the margin figure. Works best with a tall/portrait image.

\begin{marginfigure}
  \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{awkward}
  \caption{A long, but not unreasonably long, figure caption that extends into the footer and depending on your pagestyle can overwrite the page number (which looks weird, a number floating in your caption).}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

It looks like the marginfigure is vertically centered, but without restriction on how far the caption text extends down.

Can I stop this from happening, or is it on me to insert a bunch of page breaks?

(Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to latex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `marginfigure` and its caption are set in a `minipage` with its default `center` positioning, which will not break across pages.

You can either put the `marginfigure` higher on the page or ask Lars Madsen (daleif@math.au.dk), the maintainer of `memoir to do something like enabling the` minipage b`and`t` options.

In any case you, on occasions, will have to manually control the result --- `marginfigure` too low with default or `t` option will extend below the normal text or `marginfigure` too high with default or `b` option will extend above the normal text.

Comment: I don't want to break it across pages, but in this case I think the whole thing should float onto the next page?

Comment: A `marginfigure` is not a float and to make it into one would take a lot of work for, in my view, no good purpose. Have you contacted Lars Madsen?

Comment: But - the documentation says it is a float. (It's in "10.1.1 Margin floats" in the memoir docs.) But whether it is or not isn't the point, the question is why it can extend down past the limit if it was say a `figure`. I'll ping Lars.

Comment: @Doug It is a float in the sense that `\marginpar` generates a float in the margin. The implemtation used here is equivalent to `\marginpar{\parbox{4cm}{\rule{4cm}{4cm}\par some text}}` instead of your marginfigure. Try adding that to an `article` based document and you'll get the same result, extending below the bottom.

Comment: @Doug the placement gets even worse if you remove the `\parbox` and just use text, for example `\kant*[1]` from the `kantlipsum` package

Comment: @daleif is there a way to prevent it? I'm not really looking for ways to make it look worse ;-)

Comment: @Doug As I see it only as Peter mentions, manually add b t options to marginfigure or code some algorithm to detect where you are vertically on the page and the move up. It will never go to the next page as marginpar does not support it.

Comment: OK, thanks, marked as accepted!